# what is the saved file location of generated-requests.http file generated by intellij idea Rest Client?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, rest-client

The first time I created a Rest client file named `generated-requests.http` and after closing, I cannot reopen it because I don't know its file location. This is spring boot project.

Answer (score 0):

Check it under the **Scratches** node in Project tool window:
[image]

Comment: i am work with spring boot project

Comment: The project type does not matter.

Comment: the problem is there is no folder name like that in that project